# non search pikachu trash can

Tags: django, angularjs, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

Hello this may be fresh and green.

I'm looking to build a responsive web, I am familiar with django however new to AngularJS

The backend I have in mind is Deployd.com which utilizes MongoDB

may I know the perks or downs of :

1. angularjs as a web framework as compared to django

   - from research it seems that angular has awesome data binding capabilities
2. if django, why? anything that django can do well as compared to angular

   - (other then angular being hard to master)
3. compatibility of angularjs + django

   - (no speculations, people with deployment experience only please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is a front-end javascript framework.
Django is a back-end server framework.
They aren't comparable.

Comment: No worries. Everyone was new at some time :-)